# Importing products.. please wait

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2.2.6 fresh install.  I have a product file that is 80MB and when I import it I get the dreaded Please Wait...  I can never get past this.

I know the import works as I have tried it with one line.
I have increased my execution time to 3600 and it still hangs. 
I have tried Safari and Chrome.
I have switched to developer mode but no error messages are displayed.
I know the file uploads fine, as I can see it in the /var/importexport directory.
I have used the F12 function in Chrome to monitor the network traffic. 
I have looked in the log files in the var/log - nothing.

Im running out of ideas here...  I refuse to split it up - Magento2 is meant to be able to handle this... surely??!?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the error in your web server log.

and increase the value of

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

in the `php.ini` file

NOTE : make sure to restart the web server after change this.

Comment: I have tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Upgraded my dev site from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 and boom, the dread please wait as you say. Seems like Magento breaks this every other version. So sick of it.

To not waste your time, create a product in backend, export in csv and reimport without touching it. If pease wait then yup Magento is broken. This is whgat I've tried, as well as the usual increase memory blurb.